# How to remove these weird ruler lines around artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, artboard, document-setup

My illustrator opens this way by default. I have no idea why or how. I have tried tweaking settings in document setup, preferences, etc. but it always opens a new Ai document like this. My older Ai files are fine tho. Can someone please tell me how to remove these rulers around grid and how to get the normal background instead of a transparent one? [image]

Comment: Why would you choose video options if you donr want the rulers?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking at isn't weird but the artboard setup for video. They indicate the safe area for a screen, where the center of the screen would be and ruler around the outside.

The easiest way to resolve this is to simply not select a template from the Video and Film collection when you are setting up a new artboard.

However, you can easily change these in the document

- To change the grid transparency (the checkered background) head to
  **VIEW / HIDE TRANSPARENCY GRID**
- To hide (or show) the rulers on the edge head to **VIEW / RULERS /
  SHOW/HIDE VIDEO RULES**
- To hide (or show) the safe zones and cross hairs head to **ARTBOARD
  OPTIONS** and uncheck **SHOW CROSS HAIRS**, **SHOW CENTER MARK** and
  **SHOW VIDEO SAFE AREA**

Comment: Cool, it worked! 
However, when I do a document from the Video and Film collection, I followed all your pointers, and the last one does not seem to work. They're all unchecked but it the video safe area still shows. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Upload an image if you want and see if we can't narrow that down. 

If you have multiple artboards then you may need to select all and do them. Sometime if you have settings that different between different artboards, you may find it easier to select all, uncheck and check all then hit ok and then go back an uncheck all them.